# I want to select and display two columns, i.e itemcode and transdate in the subquery

Tags: mysql

```
select 
    itemcode, description, location, stocklevel, wtavg_cost, dddvalue     
from 
    hms_pha_stock c 
where 
    c.stocklevel > 0 
    and itemcode not in (select itemcode 
                         from hms_pha_tranheader a, hms_pha_transaction b 
                         where a.refno = b.refno 
                           and a.trantype = b.trantype 
                           and a.trantype in ('PTO','PIS') 
                           and b.location = 'CPH' 
                           and a.transdate between '2016-11-01' and '2016-11-08') 
    and c.location ='CPH' 
group by 
    itemcode
```

Comment: any error show in this query?

Answer (score 0):

You have used **subquery** in **where clause**. There you can select only one column to satisfy the where clause condition.

Below I have modified the query according for your requirement

```
SELECT c.itemcode, 
       description, 
       location, 
       stocklevel, 
       wtavg_cost, 
       dddvalue 
FROM   hms_pha_stock c 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT itemcode, transdate
           FROM   hms_pha_tranheader a, 
                  hms_pha_transaction b 
           WHERE  a.refno = b.refno 
                  AND a.trantype = b.trantype 
                  AND a.trantype IN ( 'PTO', 'PIS' ) 
                  AND b.location = 'CPH' 
                  AND a.transdate BETWEEN 
                      '2016-11-01' AND '2016-11-08') lJoin
ON c.itemcode = lJoin.itemcode
WHERE  c.stocklevel > 0 
       AND lJoin.itemcode IS NULL 
       AND c.location = 'CPH' 
GROUP  BY c.itemcode
```

Hope this should solve your problem

Comment: Thank you very much, its giving me an error of ambiguous field but i have added an alias

Comment: If the answer solves your problem, kindly make it as a correct answer, which would be helpful for others.

Comment: FYR, if you do not aware of how to make an answer as best answer, refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I have got the correct answer ,please guide on how to post the answer , i want to post it now

Comment: I have edited my answer to solve the ambiguous problem. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers to make an answer as best answer